# Windows application on close

Tags: c++, c, windows, midi, audio

This issue is about the MIDI application that will receive sudden overflow of MIDI buffer when the application startup.

Anyone has idea how to clear any MIDI data on queued from MIDI Yoke or LoopBe before the program accept incoming data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you are wanting to flush an input stream before you start using it.  If that is the case, then you can use a simple loop like this early in your program's start-up code (pseudo-code):

```
while input queue is not empty:
    buffer = read_from_queue()
    // Don't do anything with 'buffer'
loop
```

Essentially, read a little bit from the input queue and throw it away, then repeat until the queue is empty.  I can't give a more detailed description than that without knowing more about your program.

Comment: That not a MIDI buffer right? Mean, flush MIDI buffer before accept an incoming MIDI event when the application is launch. Any such MIDI command on Windows C/C++ API?